# How to show images in python3

Tags: python-3.x, image

I'm a beginner and I'm having problems of showing images in python3. I would like to know what are some codes that could show images in python 3,f or a mac user. Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some more context?  Where are you trying to display the image?

Your best bet is probably to open another program and give it the path to the image you want to display. To open the file `~/screenshot.png`, for example, you could run

```
from subprocess import run

run(["open", "~/screenshot.png"])
```

This is pretty delicate however.  It requires the user to have `open` installed on their computer, and for that executable to do what you expect it to do. Depending on what your usecase is, it might make more sense for you to use a graphical library to draw the image.